# Memory issues: Cluster-analysis with very large multi-scaled data in R using Gower distance and k-medoids

Tags: r, out-of-memory, cluster-analysis, large-data

I have a very large dataframe named 'data' with 350000 rows and 138 columns which I would like to use for a k-medoids clustering. I am using the code from that page: http://dpmartin42.github.io/blogposts/r/cluster-mixed-types

This is my code:

```
packages <- c("dplyr", "ISLR", "cluster", "Rtsne", "ggplot2")


if (length(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages()))) > 0) {
install.packages(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages())))  
}

rm(packages)

library(dplyr) # for data cleaning
library(ISLR) # for college dataset
library(cluster) # for gower similarity and pam
library(Rtsne) # for t-SNE plot
library(ggplot2) # for visualization

data <- read.csv("data.csv", sep = ";")


## creation of dissimilarity matrix using "Gower distance" for mixed data 
##types
gower_dist <- daisy(data,
                metric = "gower",
                type = list())
gower_mat <- as.matrix(gower_dist)
#write.table(gower_mat, file = "dissimilarity.csv")
#summary(gower_dist)


sil_width <- c(NA)
for(l in 2:8){

pam_fit <- pam(gower_dist,
             diss = TRUE,
             k = l)

sil_width[l] <- pam_fit$silinfo$avg.width
}

nclust <- which.max(sil_width) # identify index of highest value
opt.value <- max(sil_width, na.rm = TRUE) # identify highest value
ncluster <- round(mean(nclust))
valcluster <- max(opt.value)

## start PAM clustering with n clusters
pam_fit <- pam(gower_dist, diss = TRUE, k = ncluster)

pam_results <- data.sample %>%
mutate(cluster = pam_fit$clustering) %>%
group_by(cluster) %>%
do(the_summary = summary(.))


#pam_results$the_summary

#data.sample[pam_fit$medoids, ]


tsne_obj <- Rtsne(gower_dist, is_distance = TRUE)

tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
  mutate(cluster = factor(pam_fit$clustering))

ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) +
geom_point(aes(color = cluster))
```

The steps I want to perform are:

1) Create dissimilarity matrix using Gower distance for multi-scaled data

2) Look for optimal number of clusters

3) Perform k-medoids clustering

4) Visualize clustering using Rtsne for visualization of multi-dimensional data

The code works fine for a data subset up to 10000 rows.

If I try to perform the code on more rows I get memory issues. With the entire dataframe I get the error:
'Error: cannot allocate vector of size 506.9 GB'
which is created at step

```
gower_dist <- daisy(data.sample,
                metric = "gower",
                type = list(),
                warnType = FALSE) # suppress warning regarding data type
```

I know that the creation of the dissimilarity matrix needs a lot of RAM.
So my question is not about the coding but about the methodology: Is there any meaningful way to create the dissimilarity matrix and perform the clustering on the entire dataframe? 
I was thinking about two alternatives:

OPTION 1: Create the dissimilarity matrix iterative in steps of 1000 rows. I am not sure if this makes sense as the matrix shows each row by each row.

OPTION 2: Create a for loop with all steps where data subsets of 1000 rows are selected randomly and all steps are repeated many times until a representative clustering is reached. I am also not sure if this makes sense.

Is it possible to perform the code above on very large datasets in R?

Comment: How many duplicate rows do you have?

Comment: Kmedoids scales really badly. The 500 GB sounds plausible to me. Don't use a distance matrix based algorithm on such data.

Comment: I have about 3000 duplicate rows. Thank you for your advice. I wanted to use kmedoids because of its ability to use the Gower distance for multi-scaled data. Do you have any recommendation, which algorithm can be used for large multi-scaled data without using a distance matrix? Any hint would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

SLINK will require only linear memory. DBSCAN and OPTICS, too.

DBSCAN will be a bit tricky to parameterize (which value of epsilon?), but OPTICS is worth a try. I don't know if Gower can be indexed, to accelerate the algorithm.

But you'll hit the same problem later in tSNE!

What I would consider is to first work with a manageable subset only. Then, once you know what works, you can either use all data (with DBSCAN, you could try using the same epsilon, but increasing minPts for the larger data size). Or you simply add the remaining points to the same cluster as their nearest neighbor in the sample.